# AssociationMap with formatting

Tags: associations

Build an Association using AssociationMap, where the keys are the letters of the Alphabet[] and the values are the same letters with the following Style:

1. The size of the letter should be set to twice that of the letter's position in the English alphabet.
2. The Background of the nth letter in the Alphabet should be set to the nth color from the "ColorList" in the "Legacy" color scheme.(Hint:Use LetterNumber and ColorData).

While trying to solve the above problem (courtesy Wolfram U team), I could just do the plain AssociaionMap.

Input:

```
AssociationMap [f,{Alphabet[]}]
```

Output:

```
<\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}->f[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}]\>
```

Clueless about positioning (1) and setting background (2) in the needed format.

Comment: Use `Alphabet[]` (not `{Alphabet[]}`) and try `ClearAll[f]; f[letter_] := Style[letter, FontSize -> 2 LetterNumber[letter],   Background -> ColorData["Legacy"]@LetterNumber@letter];`

Comment: @kglr By Alphabet[], the output is displayed differently. Is it just difference in visual appearance with the meaning remaining the same (a mapped to f(a), b mapped to f(b)...)?

Comment: @kglr The code worked perfect. Could you please help know why ClearAll [f] is used immediately after Alphabet[]. For me, it is removing whatever assigned [a to f(a), b to f(b)...]. If that be so, how the third command works that indeed needs assignments in the first place before formatting.

Comment: SplendidDigitalSolutions, re  `ClearAll` pls see [ClearAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html). Re why you need `Alphabet[]` in the second argument of `AssociationMap`, compare the outputs from `AssociationMap[doSomethingWith, {"key1", "key2"}]` and `AssociationMap[doSomethingWith, {{"key1", "key2"}}]`.